# What sort of explosive detonators could be made without modern technology?

Tags: technology, explosions

This is a very society in the style of the 1730's Europe long before the advent of modern electronics.

While I expect wick-style fuses to still easily be made (as they were then), could anything like a timer pencil or other more modern precise detonators be made with the resources of the time?

I'm looking for particularly timed and remote trigger detonators, the more precise the better.

Comment: This looks like a question about the capabilities of a specific individual in a scenario more than it is a question about building a fictional such story-based questions are off topic for this site.

Comment: I am no chemist, but at least from the Wiki it doesn't sound over complicated to make mercury fulminate. Unsure about required purity of materials though. Then you can use clockworks (when did those become available?) to make a mechanical detonator. But even without that, there's still the equivalent of the classical mechanical alarm clock that instead strikes some flint. Such clocks came into existence in 1787. Convenient and accurate, though maybe too expensive to blow up.

Comment: I'll edit to remove specifics of the character and focus on the world.

Comment: 'Very rural' isn't terribly specific.  What technology is available...?  At the very least, give us a real-world society and a year for equivalence.

Comment: Sufficiently accurate [safety fuses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_fuse) became available in the 1830s. They are not all that hard to make if you know the trick. (The trick is to use rope making tools to make a double-walled textile tube of constant width surrounding a core of black powder and sealed from the exterior by a varnish.)

Comment: for the _detonator_ part, i instantly thought about McGuivering a [Fire Piston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_piston) with a spring.

Comment: you need to specify what kind of detonator you want, timed, remote trigger, what are you looking for it to do.

Comment: 1700 is quite advanced already, there were armed ships with gunpowder grenades. https://www.google.com/search?q=17th+century+grenade By the way, there are many answers to this already, search https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=medieval+explosives

Comment: I would suggest looking at the history of timed artillery fuzes, which required precise timing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillery_fuze#Time_fuzes .  If the wick-style / gunpowder-train-style fuzes aren't precise enough for the story's needs, take a look the clockwork based fuzes.  Bear in mind that while probably doable with 1700s era tech, each fuze will be much, much more expensive without the mass production capabilities of late 19th-early 20th century factories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timing part of the question is well answered.

But what if you have an explosive that doesn't operate simply from ignition (say, some alchemist has discovered how to make RDX and other nitrate explosives, by fooling around with saltpeter and acids and other stuff).  You want to use this stuff, because it's safer to make than gunpowder, doesn't much care about moisture, and it takes much less of it to do certain jobs.

Fortunately, detonating "initiator" compounds were known to alchemists starting in the 13th to 14th century: fulminates.  At some point, by poking at stuff (as alchemists do), someone discovered that nitric acid could be assisted in dissolving precious metals -- gold and silver -- as well as, eventually, mercury, and all of those nitrates could be reacted with alcohol to produce compounds that would explode with tremendous force (one of the earliest reports of gold fulminate said that a piece the size of a grain of rice would *blow a hole in a metal spoon*).

Silver and gold fulminate are too sensitive to be useful (that is, too dangerous to handle), but mercury fulminate was a good enough compound for this kind of purpose to be used in various capacities into the 1940s.

It's simple to make, from easily refined mercury, nitric acid, and ethanol (all very well known to alchemists before Europe had gunpowder); it's sensitive to both heat and (rather mild) impact as well as friction, but stable enough to handle without undue hazard (at least by alchemical standards).

Fulminate initiators could be remotely detonated either mechanically (via a pulled cable with friction wire or gun-type hammer mechanism) or electrically (if your world understands even simple batteries and conduction) -- or by any sort of timing mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

A clockwork  mechanism would work as a time delayed fuse to set off a reserve of gunpowder. This method was used by the Dutch during the Eighty Years War to detonate [Hellburners] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellburners) which were ships filled to the brim with black powder and shrapnel to act as gigantic bombs to destroy entire Spaniard fleets.

Answer (score 2):

Timed detonation required either a fancy timing clock mechanism, or some sort of tripwire.

Or, what **absolutely everyone** with explosives was using, which is a slowburning fuze typically made of gunpowder.
By the 1730's these were in use on a daily basis in *hundreds* to *thousands* of naval ships, artillery, and mining demolition.

A well-made and maintained naval fuze was accurate to 1 second in 3 minutes, regardless of environmental considerations, so just accuracy of timing is not a reason to eschew fuzes.

But if you are looking for an electrical detonation trigger or distance triggering via electrical signal, the first electrical **anything** was only made in the very early 1800's, and the first conductor better than a salty wet string had to wait until about 1830.
By 1730 not even batteries were available.